# Returning true on every iteration of array_key_exists() in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-key-exists

What am I trying to get is..

I do not know `check_mobile_exists(  $mobiles, $electronics )` this function is returning true all time. I want true when $mobile array key is existed in the $electronics key list and false when not existed. On this result basis I am looping the post result. But as I said that function is returning true on every iteration. Any one to suggest me what should I do now?

```
function check_mobile_exists(  $mobiles, $electronics ) {
    foreach( $mobiles as $mobile => $price ) {
        if( array_key_exists( $mobile, $electronics ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$mobiles = array(
    'iPhone' => '$350',
    'tablet' => '$100',
    'samsung' => '$200',
    'walton'  => '$60'
);

$electronics = array(
    'iPhone' => 'OK',
    'tablet' => 'will do',
    'walton' => 'No need'
);

while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    if( check_mobile_exists(  $mobiles, $electronics ) ){ // returning only true on every iterating
        echo get_the_title() .' do something....<br />';
    } else {
        echo 'Do another....';
    }
endwhile;
```

Comment: When you want to return `true`? if all `mobiles` in `electronics` array?

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I want to return true when the keys of `$mobile` is existed in `$electronics` and that time in while loop "do something" will be executed. And when key of $mobile will not existed in `$electronics` it will return false and while loop will execute "Do another ..". That means 

     1. true ===> "do something"
      2. true ===> "do something"
     3. false ====> "Do another " ... 
     4. true ==> "do something"..
in this way as the array exists in my example. @JyothiBabuAraja

Comment: Okay, I updated answer according to your need. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$mobiles = array(
    'iPhone' => '$350',
    'tablet' => '$100',
    'samsung' => '$200',
    'walton'  => '$60'
);
$electronics = array(
    'iPhone' => 'OK',
    'tablet' => 'will do',
    'walton' => 'No need'
);

while( have_posts() ): the_post();
  foreach( $mobiles as $mobile => $price ) {
    if( array_key_exists( $mobile, $electronics ) ) {
        echo get_the_title() .' do something....<br />';
    }else{
        echo 'Do another....';
    }   
  }
endwhile;
```

**UPDATED:** So as you said, without using another function you can do this.

Comment: This is printing the "do something" twice for time and later time all three time. And this way [see here](https://s30.postimg.org/xf1dmmwkh/dfddfs.png) . No working. Please check it again.

Comment: I think your `while` loop executing multiple times.

Comment: You will get as expected if you keep `foreach` out of `while` loop

Comment: But I need to some executions on the posts. That means when it returns true it will print some specific posts otherwise another one.

Comment: So, you need to iterate over all `posts` and pick specific `posts` for `mobiles` in `electronics`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131414/discussion-between-chayan-biswas-and-jyothi-babu-araja).

Answer (score 0):

Do it witout check mobile function

```
$mobiles = array(
    'iPhone' => '$350',
    'tablet' => '$100',
    'samsung' => '$200',
    'walton'  => '$60'
);
$electronics = array(
    'iPhone' => 'OK',
    'tablet' => 'will do',
    'walton' => 'No need'
);




while( have_posts() ): the_post();
  foreach ( $mobiles as $m_key => $mobile ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( $m_mey, $electronics) ) { 
        do somethin
    } else { 
        do somethin
    }
}
endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. But this is not iterating in while loop. I mean if intersection is not empty it should return true and then in while loop it will print "do something".So for first two key of `$mobile` it will return true and print "do something" at third one will be returned false and should print "Do another". Please can you check it?

Comment: And if not Mobile in electronics : Do another.. This way I want it.

Comment: The check_mobile function is then  a little lame here do it this way i have updated the answer. What do you think ?

Comment: But this is giving this result. Please [Check It](https://s30.postimg.org/xf1dmmwkh/dfddfs.png)

Comment: I see, I have created a working example here https://repl.it/EwfJ/0. Can you confirm the results ?

Can you explain what is expected ?